# Fullcalendar, jQuery ContextMenu, JS: eventClick works only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar, contextmenu

### jQuery ContextMenu breaking FullCalendar eventClick

I use slots calendar to book hourly appointments.
When I click on slot first time (opens jquery context menu) everything is okay, I get the slot event data and eventClick is called and context menu opens.
If then I clicked on another slot in the calendar it does not call eventClick, the context menu open right but with old event id.
If I clicked outside the calendar and then clicked on the slot, eventClick is called and works perfectly.
If I return false inside eventClick function it works okay (eventClick is called everytime I click on slot) but context menu does not appear

Here is the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/737

Full Calendar:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: false,
    dayRender: function (date, element, view) { },
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    eventStartEditable: false,
    select: selectDate,
    minTime: starttime + ":00:00",
    maxTime: endtime + ":00:00",
    transmitTZD: false,
    slotDuration: "00:" + slotduration + ":00",
    // disableResizing: true,
    // editable: true,
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        eventid = calEvent.id;
        shiftDate = calEvent.start;
        var status = calEvent.title.split("-")[0].trim();
        // return false;
    },
    events: {
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
    }
});
```

Context Menu:

```
$(function () {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.bookcls',
        trigger: 'left',
        callback: function (key, options) {
            checkaction(key, eventid);
        },
        items: {
            "start": { name: "start", disabled: false }
        },
        beforeOpen: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit 1:**

I found another question here with same problem, but I didn't get how that would fix my problem.
I use left click to trigger the context menu.
[contextMenu breaking FullCalendar event dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044651/contextmenu-breaking-fullcalendar-event-dragging)

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? You can check this by pressing F12 to open the developer tools, then click the Console tab and see if any errors are displayed?

Comment: No errors at all @Milney

Comment: It could be because jquery context menu uses event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() somewhere in its code. So what happens if in Google Chrome you click on the slot to show the context menu, then hide the menu, and then right-click (instead of left-click) and select Inspect Element? Chrome should show you the element that is catching the click and obstructing it.

Comment: You are right about event.preventDefault(), I found it inside the click event for the left-click trigger and I commented both lines e.preventDefault(); and e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but also that did not work, and when I right-click the event and inspected element it was div with class fc-content but I could not find the JS function being invoked @K48